# Allure java Run specific tests depending on story or feature

Tags: java, maven, allure

I have two methods in my test class:

```
@Test
@Stories( "story1")
public void test01(){
}

@Test
@Stories( "story2")
public void test02(){
}

@Test
@Stories( "story1")
public void test03(){
}
```

To run tests Im using:

```
mvn clean test site
```

It will execute all test. But my question is, how to execute tests when I want to execute only tests with specific user story (ie. story1)

I know in python it can be done by

```
py.test my_tests/ --allure_stories=story1
```

But I don't know how to do it in java using maven

Answer (score 0):

In Java there is no need for Allure to do such sort of things, because you can do it using your test runner, e.g. TestNG.
Just create `Listener` or `BeforSuite` which will check your environment variable e.g. `-DallureStories` and match it with ITestContext to disable tests not in your stories list.